# Excel 2010 - formula that formats a cell in function of another cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, format

Can i have a formula that formats a cell in function of another cell value.
Lets say, if A1=1 all the values in column B are formatted into dollars. If A1 different than 1 then all the values in column B are formatted into Euros!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use conditional formatting.

1. Select column B and go to Conditional Formatting;
2. Click on 'New Rule' and pick the last option 'Use formula ...'
3. In the input box, put `=$A$1=1` and pick the format as 'Number' > 'Currency' > 'Euro' (well, the currency you want)
4. Click OK twice.
5. Repeat steps 1-4 but with the other formatting, 'Dollars' and the formula now `=$A$1=2`.

And there goes the magic :)

Comment: Well explained. Nice answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly!!! Really appreciate it.

Comment: @XavierCunha You're welcome :)

Comment: @XavierCunha if this answers your question please mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Jerry how can I mark it ( sorry but this is the first time I use this forum and I still don't know the procedures)

Comment: @XavierCunha That's okay, don't worry! There should be the outline of a tick to the left of the answer which you can click.